# In Django Rest Framework, get all chosen groups for a request User

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to return the list of chosen groups for a particular user. We can get all groups, we can get all user permissions by group, but not the group names themselves.
e.g.

```
> Group.objects.all() //list of ALL group names
> Group.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True) //list of ALL groups' IDs
> request.resource_owner.get_group_permissions() //all group based permissions
```

Answer (score 1):

just posting answer. fyi!

> request.resource_owner.groups.all()